# Решение квадратного уравнения на Assembler

Tags: ассемблер

С помощью какой команды можно найти корень квадратный дискриминанта?
push  и fsqrt, не предлагать)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если FSQRT недоступна, то тогда можно написать (или найти в сети) процедуру на ассемблере, которая будет считать значение квадратного корня с помощью [итерационной формулы Герона](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%93%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0). Формула простая и быстро сходится.

[image]